# AngularJS: Error in iframe when trying to play a video

Tags: javascript, angularjs

These are my errors: `Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ videourl }} Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.`

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ videourl }} Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

When I add in this code which I get from research...

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
  'self',   
  'http://tvstartup.biz/**']);
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
```

...I get this error:

```
 `ReferenceError: $sceDelegateProvider is not defined at new <anonymous> (/js/app.js:295:1) at Object.instantiate (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18010:14) at $controller (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23412:28) at self.appendViewElement (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59900:24) at Object.render (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57893:41) at Object.init (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57813:20) at self.render (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59759:14) at self.register (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59717:10) at updateView (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65398:23) at /lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65382:9 <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios">`
```

Here is my code:
Js

```
 .controller('WatchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $sce) {
    $scope.title = 'Air 247';
    $scope.apiusername = '?';
    $scope.apipassword = '?';
    $scope.waid = $stateParams.wId;
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
  'self',   
  'http://tvstartup.biz/**']);
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
$scope.videourl = 'http://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/vod.php?token=c177083f3e6b9c913a691e28ce92f799&id=' + $scope.waid;

}])
```

HTML

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ videourl }}" seamless="seamless"  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen width="960" height="470" > </iframe>
```

What I want it to do is play the video that is in the iframe, but I keep getting those errors. I've also tried passing the id into the ng-src, but it did not work and I still got the same errors as the top 2.

Comment: From the documentation seems like the provider you are trying to use needs to be added in the configuration, not in the Controller https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$sceDelegateProvider

Comment: ok where do i need to add please post answer @Teknotica

Comment: if it works i will accept @Teknotica

Comment: can you post it as a answer? @Teknotica

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39669271/angularjs-ionic-error-in-iframe-when-trying-to-play-a-video @Teknotica