# AngularJS ionic - Error in iframe when trying to play a video

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

These are my errors: `Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ videourl }} Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.`

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{ videourl }} Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.
```

When I add in this code which I get from research...

```
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
  'self',   
  'http://tvstartup.biz/**']);
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
```

...I get this error:

```
 `ReferenceError: $sceDelegateProvider is not defined at new <anonymous> (/js/app.js:295:1) at Object.instantiate (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:18010:14) at $controller (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23412:28) at self.appendViewElement (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59900:24) at Object.render (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57893:41) at Object.init (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:57813:20) at self.render (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59759:14) at self.register (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:59717:10) at updateView (/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65398:23) at /lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:65382:9 <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21" class="view-container" nav-view-transition="ios">`
```

Here is my code:
Js

```
 .controller('WatchController', ['$scope', '$http', '$state', '$stateParams', '$location', '$sce', function ($scope, $http, $state, $stateParams, $sce) {
    $scope.title = 'Air 247';
    $scope.apiusername = '?';
    $scope.apipassword = '?';
    $scope.waid = $stateParams.wId;
$sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
  'self',   
  'http://tvstartup.biz/**']);
  $scope.trustSrc = function(src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
  }
$scope.videourl = 'http://tvstartup.biz/mng-channel/vpanel/vod.php?token=c177083f3e6b9c913a691e28ce92f799&id=' + $scope.waid;

}])
```

HTML

```
<iframe ng-src="{{ videourl }}" seamless="seamless"  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" allowfullscreen width="960" height="470" > </iframe>
```

What I want it to do is play the video that is in the iframe, but I keep getting those errors. I've also tried passing the id into the ng-src, but it did not work and I still got the same errors as the top 2.

Comment: Duplicate of [AngularJS: Error in iframe when trying to play a video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39644172/angularjs-error-in-iframe-when-trying-to-play-a-video). You don't need to post the same question multiple times.

Comment: @Quantastical i need help that is why i did it

Comment: and noone is helping me @Quantastical

Comment: I strongly encourage you to review the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) on StackOverflow, in particular the ["What should I do if no one answers my question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers). They suggest editing your question and providing status updates with attempts you've made. I don't say this to disrespect you or your questions, but to help acclimate you to this site and hopefully steer you to a solution that doesn't involve duplicate questions. I just don't want to see this site get abused and cluttered as it is an incredible resource.

Comment: ok thank you @Quantastical

Comment: Can someone please post a solution for ionic v2